# LibreOffice Base Basic Get form field value on load

Tags: forms, scripting, libreoffice

This works to get the value of a field at an event (say a button click):

```
Sub runatevent(Event as Object)
    dim form as Object
    dim cntrl
    form = Event.Source.Model.Parent
    cntrl = form.getByName("txtpath").currentvalue
    print(cntrl)
End Sub
```

However when I try to fire this on the Form's "After Record Change" event, I get an error: "property or method not found: Model"

How do I get the value of "txtpath" on the "After Record Change" Form event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure this out, I used [XrayTool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) on the `Event` object.  This is what worked:

```vb
form = Event.Source
```

As in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306910/simple-python-script-to-get-a-libreoffice-base-field-and-play-on-vlc), I suggest reading the value from the result set:

```vb
nameCol = form.findColumn("PATH")
print(form.getString(nameCol))
```

The idea is that the form is based on a result set, so you can just read from the result set rather than getting a control from the form and then checking the value of the control.  Just a little more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: except my data is in fields (text blocks) not in columns... so findColumn() appears not to work. How do I find something simple like what methods does the form object now allow? My field is named txtpath which displays data path, it has the label <path> (aka lblpath). Thanks!

Comment: Moved discussion to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117030/room-for-jim-k-and-trees4theforest-libreoffice-base-get-form-field